# Android RxJava Observable blocking ui

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm using rxJava and retrofit for my request, but when I launch a request my application freeze until the request is finish.

This is how I launch the request in the fragment

```
MappingService.postSearch()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Consumer<SearchResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(SearchResponse response) throws Exception {
                            searchResponse = response;
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                            throwable.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }));
```

I read some stackoverflow question, and if I understand it well subscribeOn will launch the postSearch() method in Schedulers.io() and with observeOn the subscribe part will be executed on my mainThread.

The postSearch method launch this method :

```
public class RequestService<T> {

   public Single<T> launchRequest(final Single single) {
    return single.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).onErrorResumeNext(
            new Function<Throwable, SingleSource<? extends Response<T>>>() {
                @Override
                public SingleSource<? extends Response<T>> apply(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    return Single.error(ErrorUtils.asRetrofitException(throwable));
                }
            }).flatMap(new Function<Response<T>, Single<T>>() {
        @Override
        public Single<T> apply(@NonNull Response<T> response) throws Exception {
            if (response.code() == Integer.valueOf(ErrorUtils.CODE_200)) {
                return Single.just(response.body());
            } else {
                return Single.error(new Throwable(String.valueOf(response.code())));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

If an error appear the Single.error is trigger otherwise the Single.just() with the response is trigger.

I try to use an Observable instead of a Single, I always have the freeze.

EDIT : the postSearch method

```
public static Single<SearchResponse> postSearch() {
    return new RequestService<SearchResponse>().launchRequest(getApi().postSearch());
}
```

The getApi() method :

```
 private static MappingApi mappingApi;

private static MappingApi getApi() {
     if (mappingApi == null){
        mappingApi = MappingApi.Factory.create();
    }
    return mappingApi;
}
```

It return the launchRequest method, with the param `getApi().postSearch()` it's my declaration of POST with url inside my Api interface

```
public interface MappingApi {
    class Factory {
        public static MappingApi create() {
            return RetrofitHelper.buildRetrofit().create(MappingApi.class);
        }
     }

     @POST("mapping/classifieds")
     Single<Response<SearchResponse>> postSearch();
}
```

Comment: The problem may be in `postSearch`, it's not obvious from your code how `postSearch` invokes the `launchRequest`.

Comment: I made an edit of my question with the postSearch method

Comment: What happens in the RequestService constructor?

Comment: Thanks for comment the requestService has no default constructor it's simply a generic class I added the full interface code for the request but I'm not sure it's relevant, to resolve the freeze I wrap the call inside a AsyncTask, but it's really weird If I'm using retrofit and Rx it's for don't use AsyncTask anymore

Comment: Why do you create API on every request? Perhaps that is the slow part

Comment: I edit my code with a Singleton pattern for MappingApi, but it's not changing I always have the Freeze, I really don't understand and if I wrap my call with the AsyncTask it's working well

Comment: How do you know it is this code that is freezing your app? Everything looks correct. Have you tried checking on which thread is request really executed?